# Probability that the number of Ferraru chocolate bars is greater than the expected number of Neptune bars

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Three different types of chocolate bar products are sold in a large jar.

In any given jar, 20% of the chocolate bars would be Snacker bars, 50% would be Neptune bars, and 30% would be Ferraru bars.

Four bars were randomly selected from the jar.

Determine the probability that the number of Ferraru bars is greater than the expected number of Neptune bars?

Answer (score 1):

The expected amount of Neptune bars is the probability of drawing a neptune bar, multiplied by the amount of draws.

$ Neptune_{expected} = (.50) \times 4 = 2$

Now account for all of the possible outcomes where more Ferraru bars are drawn than the expected amount of Neptune bars:

3 Ferraru, 1 other

4 Ferraru

Now, find the probability of each of these outcomes. The sum of these probabilities represents the probability that more than 2 Ferraru bars are drawn.

4 Ferraru:  $(.30)^4 = 0.0081 $

This represents drawing a Ferraru 4 times in a row. There is no need to consider order for this outcome, as there is only one.

3 Ferraru, 1 other:  $ ((.30)^3 \times (.70)) \times 4 = 0.0756 $

The $.70$ represents drawing any bar other than Ferraru ($1 - .30$). There are four orders in which this outcome could occur (drawing the other bar first, second, third, or last), so this probability is multiplied by 4.

Summing the probabilities of these outcomes yields $P = 0.0837 $, so there is a 8.37% probability that the number of Ferraru bars is greater than the expected number of Neptune bars.

**Edit: I misread the questions as pointed out by Sambo, thank you!**

Comment: Careful: the question asks whether the number of Ferraru bars is greater than the expected number of Neptune bars; NOT the number of Neptune bars drawn.

Comment: @Sambo good catch, thank you! I have edited my answer to reflect this.